# "Debimos haber viajado" vs "debimos viajar" / "Debimos ir corriendo" vs "debimos correr"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, tiempos-verbales

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre

> **Debimos haber viajado** al menos una hora antes de detenernos frente a una casa pequeña

y

> **Debimos viajar** al menos....

Un ejemplo similar: *ir corriendo* y *correr*.

Comment: No veo semejanzo entre *viajar* y *haber viajado* e *ir corriendo* y *correr*.  Te recomiendo que hagas dos preguntas diferentes.

Comment: @guifa pero hay uno. Mira profudamente

Comment: taruka: te puedo prometer que son cosas muy diferentes.  en una pides la diferencia entre el uso de un verbo simple y un verbo compuesto, y en la otra pides la diferencia «similar» entre un verbo y otro verbo con el anterior en gerundio.  Aparte del uso de un verbo y dos verbos, *no hay semejanza*

Comment: @guifa haz la respuesta explicando eso entonces

Comment: ‘We must have travelled’ vs ‘we must / are required to travel’? Estoy de acuerdo con @guifa, no son ejemplos similares.

Comment: taruka: lo siento, pero en este sitio intentamos mantener que cada pregunta tenga, pues, solo una pregunta.  Si algún otro quiere responderte, bienvenido sea, pero yo no a contestar hasta que haya una sola pregunta.  Además, las mejores preguntas aquí también indica de dónde viene la duda.  Por ejemplo, ¿cuál es para ti la diferencia?  ¿hay algún contexto que te ha dado la duda?

Comment: Si es una sola pregunta, es demasiado general para responderla sin más.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo con los comentarios a la pregunta respecto de que no hay demasiada similitud entre los pares (1) *haber viajado/viajar* y (2) *ir corriendo/correr*. No obstante, creo que puede trazarse algún paralelo entre ambos.

La principal diferencia entre:

1.a. **Debimos haber viajado** al menos una hora antes de detenernos frente a una casa pequeña (también: Debemos haber viajado...)

y

1.b. **Debimos viajar** al menos una hora antes de detenernos frente a una casa pequeña

es que 1.a. sólo puede expresar deducción acerca del pasado (**supongo/calculo** que viajamos al menos una hora ...). En cambio, 1.b. puede expresar lo mismo que 1.a., pero también puede expresar obligación en el pasado (**tuvimos que** viajar ...)

En el caso de:

2.a. **Debimos ir corriendo** al menos una hora antes de detenernos frente a una casa pequeña

y

2.b. **Debimos correr** al menos una hora antes de detenernos frente a una casa pequeña

2.a. sólo parece expresar obligación en el pasado (**tuvimos que** ir corriendo ...), mientras que la interpretación de deducción en el pasado sería algo exigida. En cambio, 2.b. puede expresar, además de obligación, deducción  en el pasado (**supongo/calculo** que corrimos al menos una hora ...).